# Chrome isn't correctly displaying "rgba()" styles in some element backgrounds... (no alpha blending)

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, internet-explorer-9, rgba

I'm putting together a page, and am really struggling with backgrounds across browsers.

The page uses a number of alpha-blended backgrounds, box shadows and border-radii and it is composited almost entirely using inline styles (essentially there are few/no CSS classes used).

IE9 is my primary browser, and in it, the page looks great. However, on Chrome (and I'm told Firefox), most of my alpha-blended backgrounds render either not-at-all (transparent), or as solid colors! I'm using Standards Mode with an HTML5 !DOCTYPE declaration, so it's not as though I'm leveraging IE quirks or anything!

Clearly on IE versions before 9, the backgrounds (and other things are problematic). But I'm not concerned with supporting ancient software, and those users get a browsing experience that they deserve.

The common refrain for years has been that "transparency on IE sucks!", so I was comfortable in expecting that if I got it to work adequately on IE (typically the worst platform), then the others would just fall in line, but here I am struggling in the opposite direction! I'm using the standard "rgba(r,g,b,a);" directive on the "background-Color" attribute so I'm not using any radical DirectX filters or other magic, nevertheless, on (NOT Internet Explorer 9+) browsers, I'm getting some non-alpha-blended results (sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't).

The site can be previewed at: https://net-xpert.com/ -- All of the pull-down menus are supposed to have translucent backgrounds, and so too the hovering link-bar at the bottom of the page. Also if you go to the "Ask us a Question" page, the dialog there should have tinted backgrounds on all of the input fields...

Oh, lastly, I am ENTIRELY LOATHE to implement ANY b/s, browser/platform-specific, 'experimental' style-codes! Anything in CSS2/3 is fine, but I simply REFUSE to use any kind of "-browser-some-quirky-CSSAttribute" styles! (I wish more developers would do this too! -- then browser manufacturers would be under greater pressure to adopt these STANDARDS and our lives would be SO MUCH EASIER, but I digress...)

Anyway, any insight on a standards-compliant solution would be greatly appreciated (even if it's just a communal acknowledgement that "ya, Chrome et al is currently not implementing this correctly...", at least then I'll know there's nothing to be done about it...)

Thanks!

Comment: rgba works just fine in Chrome at least since 2010, check out browser support table here: http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Comment: You should really not use inline styling. Just saying.

Comment: If something is working on IE and NOT working on Chrome and Firefox it's IE that has a bug.

Comment: @Kondrad Dzwinel : Did you look at the page? Because when I compare side-by-side with Chrome, you can see the issue clearly... So what you're saying is that, if `<div style='position:absolute;top:10px;left:10px;width:300px;height:300px;border-radius:5px;box-shadow:5px 5px 5px #000000;border:solid 1px white;color:white;background-Color:rgba(11,6,77,0.70);'>Hello World</div>` Renders correctly on IE9, but has no alpha on Chrome, that's an IE bug?

Comment: So that's it then? Two rote answers that don't in any way shape or form address the _actuality_ of the problem I'm experiencing?

Comment: Also, to address the comments above, that reference page (which I'd seen beforehand) was written MONTHS before IE9 was released; the page I referenced is CLEAR EVIDENCE that rgba() DOES NOT work "just fine" in Chrome. OPEN that page in Chrome and IE and you will SEE that the drop-down menu backgrounds are SOLID COLOURS on Chrome, but are properly alpha-blended in IE. This is also true in Firefox and Safari. As far as I can tell, NONE of the non-IE browsers are able to correctly alpha-blend those rgba() backgrounds (though, weirdly, they DO manage to blend some other background elements?)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is a very late answer, but maybe this'll still be of use to you (your site still seems to be up and running).

I have a should-work-for-you solution, assuming that you can modify one of your stylesheets.  As to WHY you've encountered this problem ..?  I can only speculate, because I don't know how to recreate your exact configuration.

The fix;

```
div[id^=mainMenuOverDiv] {
  background-color: rgba(128,128,128,0.9) !important;
}
```

I'm not a fan of using `!important` unecessarily, and you may be able to remove that by using greater specificity.  I've tested this in Firefox, though and it seems to work - obviously, you'll want to substitute the actual rgba(x,x,x,x) values with your own.

You seem to be using some JavaScript (I'm assuming) which randomizes the DIV ID every time you hover over the menu - but the beginning remains consistent (i.e. one time it will be `#mainMenuOverDivjkhasdfsd89f9f9sdfl3l4l34lfdbvbc`, then the next, it'll be `#mainMenuOverDivLSDklsdkmlzxncbzmxnc90234xcvassf`).  Using the 'starts with' CSS selector (as provided in the example), you can still isolate the menu despite this potential spanner in the works.

It's interesting (and probably insightful) that this even works, given that inline CSS usually can't be overridden.

As for why this is happening, one possibility is that some JavaScript generated code is not correctly porting over to the non-IE browsers.  Alternatively, if you're using it anywhere, code minification may also break some functionality (and vary between browsers) - many minification plugins need to be tweaked for individual setups to ensure that everything continues to work fine as one size does not necessarily fit all.  For example, you might find that on one site you can minify everything except the JavaScript, while on another site, JavaScript is fine, but you can't minify inline CSS, etc.  Google Analytics code sometimes falls victim to this.

So to my eye, the issue possibly isn't to do with IE/Chrome/Firefox or Safari - transparency is working fine on all of them - I think it's most likely the way your code is being manipulated or delivered to the browser.

Hope that helps in some way.  Let me know if you can't use an external stylesheet and I'll try to find an alternative.